# Using ServletContextListener with top-down JAX-WS WebService in Websphere

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, servletcontextlistener, top-down

I have a top-down JAX-WS webservice generated in RAD 8.5 for Websphere 8.5.

I would like to use ServletContextListener to initialise the log4j set-up for the webservice app deployed on websphere.

I created a listener that implements ServletContextListener and ServletContextAttributeListener and added @WebListener annotation to the class ( instead of putting it in web.xml ) but that does not get invoked when I start the webservice application.

According to [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/topic/com.ibm.webservice.jaxws.creation.doc/topics/cjaxwsruntime.html) link

> A WEB-INF/web.xml file.  The web.xml does not contain servlet or
>   servlet-mapping elements. The WebSphere Application Server runtime
>   defines them dynamically as the module is loaded.

What do I need to do to so that my log4j set-up in initialised or in other words to make sure that the listener is invoked?